# A Lifetime problem in Rust, a Dangling Reference

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm a rust beginner and I just learned the concept of lifetime in rust. In a tutorial, it gave me a code below

```
fn longer<'a>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if s2.len() > s1.len() {
        s2
    } else {
        s1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r;
    {
        let s1 = "rust";
        let s2 = "ecmascript";
        r = longer(s1, s2);
        println!("{} is longer", r);
    }
}
```

It told me that only use lifetime comment to tell the two reference have the same lifetime, so it can return a reference.
So I tried the code myself and changed the code a little bit as below

```
fn main() {
    let r;
    {
        let s1 = "rust";
        let s2 = "ecmascript";
        r = longer(s1, s2);
    }
    println!("{} is longer", r);
}
```

It turned out that the code passed the compile and ran correctly, but I think at the `println!` phase, r should be a Dangling Reference, so could anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: It's not because those are references with `'static` lifetime

Comment: Why exactly do you think the reference should be dangling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literals have a `'static` lifetime, therefore they are valid for as long as the program is running.

That's why your inner block is **not** returning a reference to local variable, but a reference to global application memory.

If you changed the string literals to owned strings, you will get the expected error message:

```rust
fn main() {
    let r;
    {
        let s1 = "rust".to_owned();
        let s2 = "ecmascript".to_owned();
        r = longer(&s1, &s2);
    }
    println!("{} is longer", r);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `s1` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |         r = longer(&s1, &s2);
  |                    ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     }
  |     - `s1` dropped here while still borrowed
8 |     println!("{} is longer", r);
  |                              - borrow later used here
```

Comment: thanks! I quickly learn that  ```let s1 = "rust"``` is different from ```let s1 = String::from("rust")```